# How should we test the new write-mode comments functionality?

Tags: support, discussion

Endpoints which write public content are much harder to test. What's the best way to test the new comments functionality without having to post to real threads?

I have seen the [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) web proxy suggested, but my trial has run out, and if I remember correctly, it was a bit tricky setting it up so that HTTPS endpoints could be used.

If the Stack Apps team is fine with it, I would be happy for other developers to write to this very thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `preview` is for.

Every write method takes a parameter called `preview` (the test console defaults it to true for testing purposes).  When it's explicitly set to true, the method goes through all the validation it otherwise would but stops *just short* of actually committing the data.  Preview calls also don't consume any of a user's write quota.

It's basically built for helping you test that you're calling the API correctly without actually causing any side effects.